# React : When I'm Passing props inside the carousel then each card is using one carousel and stacking like card

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I'm passing props inside a carousel then each card is using the carousel creating multiple carousel of every cards. Carousel is coming inside every card making stacks of multiple carousel.

Please help me I'm solving this problem I've been stuck for hours inside this problem.

[Output Image File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfZJT.jpg)

```
import Carousel from 'react-elastic-carousel';

const SlideChild = ({ title, category }) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const onOpenModal = () => setOpen(true);
    const onCloseModal = () => setOpen(false);
    return (
        <>
            <Carousel
                enableSwipe={true}
                enableAutoPlay
                autoPlaySpeed={3000}
                className='slider'
            >
                <div class='wrapper'>
                    <div class='cards'>
                        <p className='name' onClick={onOpenModal}>
                            {title}{' '}
                        </p>
                        //Modal content
                        <a className='category'>{category}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Carousel>
        </>
    );
};
const Slider1 = () => {
    const products = Data.map(product => (
        <SlideChild desc={product.desc} title={product.title} />
    ));
    return <>{products}</>;
};
```

Comment: You made an array of carousel so it's normal if you have one carousel for each product. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-elastic-carousel look at the documentation it's straightforward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of SlideChild has a carousel in it and you are calling SlideChild for every product. You need to move the carousel into your Slider1 definition.